# How to configure a template for class files in a Java project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, configuration, ide

I am a IntelliJ-Idea(Community version) newbie and currently got stuck on making a template of class files in a Java project.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Have you checked related article in documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-file-and-code-templates.html ?

Comment: I actually checked from there, but where is **Editor | File and Code Templates** I am not able to find this in my IntelliJ?

Comment: Full path "File | Settings (or "IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences") | Editor | File and Code Templates

Comment: @y.bedrov Great! Thanks a lot :) Could you plz answer it so that I vote for it to be right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could configure custom templates in "File | Settings (or "IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences") | Editor | File and Code Templates": https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-file-and-code-templates.html